# "Error: Specified stack size exceeds hard limit" occurs during install

Tags: macos, error

I've been trying to install a program for electron microscopy reconstruction on OS X 10.7 and when I execute it on `tcsh` I got the following message:

```
Error: specified stack size exceeds hard limit
```

I've been trying to change the hard limit using `limit` without any success.

Comment: What do you see for ulimit -a? Also what reconstruction package are you using? (We use a version of Reconstruct on windows used by neurology types, but we're always looking for something nicer!)